# API Returns Unauthorized when doing a patch from javascript client

Tags: axios, identityserver4

I'm doing a patch to an API that uses Identity Server for authentication. When I run it on Postman the patch works perfectly

```
http://localhost:90909/api/products/3434

Headers =  { 
   Authorization: Bearer <token>
   Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
}

Body: 
[
    {
     "op" : "replace",
     "path" : "/DESCRIPTION",
     "value" : "bruhhh"
    }
]
```

But when I execute the patch on my Reactjs using axios it would return Unauthorized:

```
static update(data){
        let config = {
            data : [],
            headers: { 
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + data.access_token,
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json-patch+json'           
            }     
        }

        config.data.push(
                {
                 "op" : "replace",
                 "path" : "/DESCRIPTION",
                 "value" : "you da best"
                }

        )

        return axios.patch(root + '/api/products/' + data.product.id, config);

}
```

I have my Cors setup to accept requests from this port:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {

                options.AddPolicy("JSClient", builder =>
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9999")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

So I'm not sure what else I'm missing.

**EDIT**
Fixed the header for postman

Error I see on the Identity Server logs

```
[msg=Log Error];[msg=Exception while initializing Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.TelemetryInitializers.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, exception message - System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.AspNetCoreEventSource' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.AspNetCoreEventSource..ctor()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.AspNetCoreEventSource..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.TelemetryInitializers.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer.OnInitializeTelemetry(HttpContext platformContext, RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry, ITelemetry telemetry)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient.Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)]
```

Here's another log output from serilog

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:90909/api/products/3434  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      Policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 15.8032ms 204 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 PATCH http://localhost:90909/api/products/3434 application/json;charset=UTF-8 805
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      Policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed for user: (null).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action InventoryApi.Controllers.ProductsController.Update (InventoryApi) in 46.6963ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 127.3384ms 401
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the problem at the API side?

Comment: Isn't the header `Bearer` format different in both ?

Comment: in postman also it should be like `Authorization:Bearer {{token}}` if you're using Basic Authentication (As in react code)

Comment: I just debugged it. There's only one error and I updated the post. Also updated what it should look like for the postman request

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. You could try "stringify"ing the data. That worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is newly an issue with the latest System.Text.Json library for .NET Core 3+; if you migrated from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json, the consensus for now is to switch it back.