# CORS on .Net Core API returns 401 Unauthorized from axios request

Tags: cors, .net-core, axios, identityserver3, identityserver4

**What I'm trying to do**

I want to send a PATCH request to my API from a React frontend. The API uses Identity Server 4 for validation of the request.

**What's happening**

The request works and goes through the controller from POSTMAN but it doesn't when it's coming from my frontend. It throws an Unauthorized response when it's coming from the axios request.

Additional note, the get request works great from the frontend. The get methods are also protected by Identity Server

**Postman request**

```
http://localhost:90909/api/products/3434

    Headers =  { 
       Authorization: Bearer <token>
       Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
    }

    Body: 
    [
        {
         "op" : "replace",
         "path" : "/DESCRIPTION",
         "value" : "bruhhh"
        }
    ]
```

**React**

```
 static update(data){
            let config = {
                data : [],
                headers: { 
                    'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + data.access_token,
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json-patch+json'           
                }     
            }

            config.data.push(
                    {
                     "op" : "replace",
                     "path" : "/DESCRIPTION",
                     "value" : "you da best"
                    }

            )

            return axios.patch(root + '/api/products/' + data.product.id, config);

    }
```

**CORS setup**

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {

                options.AddPolicy("JSClient", builder =>
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9999")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

**Logs**

I have enabled a few logs. Here's some that I already [posted from a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237771/api-returns-unauthorized-when-doing-a-patch-from-javascript-client?noredirect=1#comment81425680_47237771)

And below is what I got from now

**Preflight**

The following error seems to happen during the pre flight check of CORS.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Writing to the response body is invalid for responses with status code 204.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.HandleNonBodyResponseWrite()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.<WriteAsyncAwaited>d__199.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at InventoryApi.Utilities.AnotherLoggingMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in F:\My Site Projects\TestProjects\InventoryApi\AnotherLoggingMiddleware.cs:line 43
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in InventoryApi.dll
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2017-11-15T03:42:56.0180842Z","tags":{"ai.internal.nodeName":"yay-PC","ai.operation.id":"0HL9BRASKOUFU:00000003","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.0.0","ai.operation.name":"OPTIONS /api/products/1020","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"yay-PC"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request","severityLevel":"Error","properties":{"{OriginalFormat}":"An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request","DeveloperMode":"true","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","Exception":"System.InvalidOperationException: Writing to the response body is invalid for responses with status code 204.\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.HandleNonBodyResponseWrite()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.<WriteAsyncAwaited>d__199.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at InventoryApi.Utilities.AnotherLoggingMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in F:\\My Site Projects\\TestProjects\\InventoryApi\\AnotherLoggingMiddleware.cs:line 51\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware:Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
```

I checked the networking tab of the browser and I get a 204 and then immediately get a 401 after it sends the request again after the preflight request.

**This is the 204**

```
General
Request URL:http://localhost:90909/api/products/1020
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:204 No Content
Remote Address:[::1]:90909
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:99999
Date:Wed, 15 Nov 2017 04:24:24 GMT
Server:Kestrel
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RjpcTXkgU2l0ZSBQcm9qZWN0c1xUZXN0UHJvamVjdHasdfaseemVudG9yeUFwaVxhcGlccHJvZHVjdHNcMTAyMA==?=
Request Header:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:PATCH
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:90909
Origin:http://localhost:99999
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
```

**This is the 401 response for the request after the preflight**

```
General
Request URL:http://localhost:90909/api/products/1020
Request Method:PATCH
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:[::1]:90909
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Header
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:99999
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 15 Nov 2017 04:24:24 GMT
Server:Kestrel
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RjpcTXkgU2l0ZSBQcm9qZWN0c1xUZXN0UHJvamVjdHasdfaseemVudG9yeUFwaVxhcGlccHJvZHVjdHNcMTAyMA==?=
Request Header
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:850
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:90909
Origin:http://localhost:99999
Referer:http://localhost:99999/inventory/products
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
{data: [{op: "replace", path: "/DESCRIPTION", value: "you da best"}], headers: {,…}}
data
:
[{op: "replace", path: "/DESCRIPTION", value: "you da best"}]
headers
:
{,…}
```

Answer (score 0):

The server which is getting the request needs to have access enabled.

For example, on an apache server, in the configuration file add the Header set Access-Control-Allow-**Origin**:

```
<Directory />
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://ipaddress:[port]"
</Directory>
```

Where the **origin** is wherever react is being served from....

Postman, most likely, is configured to allow any origin to access...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Hey, sorry i forgot to add my setup. But i had that setup on my api level by enabling the specific address. I edited the post